# Best way to cover bedroom doorway that has no door?

Tags: doors, door-frame

I have recently moved to a new 'two room' apartment which I guess was formerly a one room apartment that was that was split in two by a wall whose stability I cannot really vouch  for. The main problem is that this wall features a doorway. This doorway connects the living room which has a very large window that lets in a lot of light to the bedroom. We have not intention to cover the living room window because we love the light there, but we want to darken the bedroom for sleep. This, which is our main concern, I guess could be solved by a curtain.
Is there any we could also put something that attenuates sound a bit? How complicated is it to install a door?

Any alternatives, either helping with the sound or not, are highly welcome.

Comment: Double curtain, one on each side of the door, attenuates sound and light better than a single curtain setup.

Answer (score 4):

A heavy or multi-layered or heavy multi-layered curtain would attenuate sound as well as many doors, and seems about right for this "wall" as described. Sandwich a blanket (or more than one) between more decorative surface layers.

Answer (score 0):

My father in law put a mirror up on both sides of an opening between a formal dinning room & the foyer. You could easily put some foam insulation in between the mirrors on both sides. You may not want a mirror in the living room in which case I might suggest a piece of wood that you paint that color. If you want the opening to stay usable then a door is your best bet. Maybe check into a pocket door so you don't chew up space in either room.

Comment: A mirror and foam as a door? -